# Changing the basis in diagonalization: why doesn't it work?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, diagonalization, change-of-basis

I read the theorem  on *Apostol Calculus II* :

> Theorem $4.10$
>
> Let $T : V \to V$ be a linear transformation, where $V$ has scalars in
> $F$, and $\dim V = n$. Assume that the characteristic polynomial of
> $T$ has $n$ distinct roots $\lambda_1,\dots, \lambda_n$ in $F$. Then
> we have:
>
> - The corresponding eigenvectors $u_1,\dots,u_n$ form a basis for $V$.
> - The matrix of $T$ relative to the ordered basis $U = [u_1,\dots,u_n]$ is the diagonal   matrix $\Lambda$ having the
>   eigenvalues as diagonal entries:
>
> $$\Lambda = \text{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n) $$
>
> - If $A$ is the matrix of $T$ relative to another basis $E = [e_1,\dots, e_n]$ then $$\Lambda = C^{-1}AC$$ where $C$ is the
>   nonsingular matrix relating the two bases by the equation $U = EC$.

But something went wrong when I applied it:

I took the matrix $A= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\5 & 4\end{bmatrix}$ and I tried to find the matrix $C$ in  $\Lambda =C^{-1}AC$ :

First, I found the eigenvalues which are $6$ and $-1$, then I chose the eigenvectors $\begin{pmatrix}2  \\5 \end{pmatrix}$  and  $\begin{pmatrix}1  \\-1 \end{pmatrix}$ which then give me the matrix $C = U =\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 \\5 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ **if** I choose for the $E$ mentioned in the theorem above the basis composed by the unit coordinate vectors. Then $C^{-1} = \frac{1}{7} \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 5 & -2\end{bmatrix}$ which indeed gives me

$$\Lambda  = C^{-1} A C =  \begin{bmatrix}
                              6 & 0 \\
                              0 & -1
                             \end{bmatrix}$$

which is the correct result.

But then I tried to use a different basis instead of the one composed by the unit coordinate vectors, I chose $E = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and I used for $U$ the same matrix as before as I think it should be done, so $U = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 \\5 & -1\end{bmatrix}$, then, since $C = E^{-1}U$ and $C^{-1} = U^{-1}E$, we have that $\Lambda = U^{-1}EAE^{-1}U$.

However, calculating it on Wolfram unfortunately [doesn't return a diagonal matrix](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28inverse+of+%5B%5B2%2C1%5D%2C%5B5%2C-1%5D%5D%29+*+%5B%5B1%2C0%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%5D%5D+*+%5B%5B1%2C2%5D%2C%5B5%2C4%5D%5D+*+%28inverse+of+%5B%5B1%2C0%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%5D%5D%29+*+%5B%5B2%2C1%5D%2C%5B5%2C-1%5D%5D).

Where did I make a mistake? Am I misapplying the theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

The matrix $A$ represents the linear transformation $L$ (this is not a matrix) in the standard basis, and in this standard basis the linear transformation $L$ is characterized by the eigenvectors and the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$. But, if you change the basis to a new basis $E$, te same linear transformation is represented by another matrix $B=EAE^{-1}$ that have different eigenvectors (that represent the same eigenspace but in the new basis), and in this new representation of the same eigenspace, the eigenvalues are, in general, different.

Comment: why the eigenvalues are in general different? If I change basis for a linear transformation this doesn't change the eigenvalues of it

Comment: thanks @Emilio for the answer anyway, it is helping me a lot!

Comment: The eigenvalues are the same but the eigenvectors or at least some of them will look different (have a different representation in coordinates). They are geometrically the same vectors of course.